# The Validation Set Approach

Tags: r, mean

I am studying the book ISLR on my own

```
library(ISLR)
set.seed(1)
train=sample(392,196)
lm.fit=lm(mpg~horsepower, data= Auto, subset=train)
attach(Auto)
mean((mpg-predict(lm.fit,Auto))[-train]^2)
23.26601
```

If I don't use the `attach()`

```
library(ISLR)
set.seed(1)
train=sample(392,196)
lm.fit=lm(mpg~horsepower, data= Auto, subset=train)
mean((mpg-predict(lm.fit,data=Auto))[-train]^2)
97.06483
```

Why the result change substantially?

Also, I don't know the syntax of this code `mean((mpg-predict(lm.fit,data=Auto))[-train]^2)`;

**what does `[]` represent?**
Also, why `mpg-predict`,we usually use `~` for formula?

I tried to use `?mean` but it didn't show the answers.

Many thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I can't reproduce your second output 97.06483.  It is possible that you have `attach`ed other datasets and some objects may have masked the `Auto$mpg` column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to predict.lm is not "data", it is `newdata`. So the first set of instruction matched the `Auto` dataframe to the `newdata` argument. If you run the second set of instructions with `newdata` as the parameter, you get the same result:

```
mean((mpg-predict(lm.fit,newdata=Auto))[-train]^2)
[1] 23.26601
```

When you execute `mpg-predict(lm.fit,newdata=Auto))` you are getting the residuals from the model. You are asking for the difference of the mpg variable value and the prediction for the that variable. (It's just a minus sign between expression `mpg - predict(...)`.

The next part of the code `[-train]` is removing the training set from the consideration. This is often called the "out-of-bag" residuals when you are doing cross validation.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `attach`ing, use `with`

```
with(Auto, mean((mpg-predict(lm.fit,Auto))[-train]^2))
#[1] 23.26601
```

---

The use of `-` on 'train' in (`?Extract` - `[`) is subsetting the elements from the vector by removing those positions created by the `sample`, before taking the `mean` of power

```
with(Auto, (mpg-predict(lm.fit,Auto)))
```

---

If we don't use `attach` or `with`, the 'mpg' object is not found in the global environment.  Therefore, it would result in error

```
mean((mpg-predict(lm.fit,data=Auto))[-train]^2)
Error in mean((mpg - predict(lm.fit, data = Auto))[-train]^2) : 
  object 'mpg' not found
```

If the OP got different value, then `mpg` may be from a different data

---

Regarding the use of `~` in formula, according to `?lm`

> Models for lm are specified symbolically. A typical model has the form response ~ terms where response is the (numeric) response vector and terms is a series of terms which specifies a linear predictor for response. A terms specification of the form first + second indicates all the terms in first together with all the terms in second with duplicates removed. A specification of the form first:second indicates the set of terms obtained by taking the interactions of all terms in first with all terms in second. The specification first*second indicates the cross of first and second. This is the same as first + second + first:second.

Comment: can i ask what ```mpg-predict``` means, especially the symbol ```-```

Comment: @MathildaFang That is just taking the difference of Actual i.e. 'mpg' value with the predictted value from the model to get the deviation.  Then, you are taking the squared devation and its mean i.e. something like a `MAPE` to give some kind of accuracy measurement for your prediction based on that lm model

Comment: I got it. Excellent explanation, thanks for you help!!

Comment: @MathildaFang this becomes important when you have multiple models and you want to select the best model from them i.e. the mean deviation is less i.e. your prediction is more accurate